# How to allow discord bot to respond to webhook. Python. Discord.py

Tags: discord.py

I have a problem trying to get a webhook to interact with a bot
For some reason, the bot doesn't respond to commands initiated by the webhook
Is there a way to make sure it initiates?
It works normally otherwise

My command:

```py
# registering new commands that can be called by the flask webhook
@client.command()
async def new_message_received(ctx, trade_hash: str = ''):
    print(f'New Trade Received! {trade_hash}')
    paxful_cogs = client.get_cog('Paxful_Cogs')
    await paxful_cogs.new_trade_received(trade_hash=trade_hash)
    await ctx.send(f'{trade_hash} executed.')
    print(f'Trade Done Execution! {trade_hash}')
```

My webhooks are sent successfully, but the bot does not respond to them.

Bot Responds to Me, but not to webhook.
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Okay, figured it out with a lot of help from the python discord server.

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    # Manually get the invocation context from the message
    ctx = await client.get_context(message)

    # Verify that the context has a command and can be used
    if ctx.valid:
        # Invoke the command using the earlier defined bot/client/command
        await client.invoke(ctx)
```

[https://i.gyazo.com/d23edb65efeeaa834c5de33d70f00484.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vgMF.png)

Basically, we're overriding the `on_message` fx, checking to see if the message matches our prefix/command structure with `ctx.valid` and then forcing the command to be processed with `client.invoke(ctx)` regardless if it's from a bot/webhook or not.